# wp_set_object_terms called from added_post_meta/updated_post_meta hook

Tags: php, wordpress

It happens so that upon addition/update of certain meta key I need to do some actions and add custom taxonomy terms to a post. 
Let's say that addition is like this (and it works perfectly if called from 'publish_post' action but at this point post meta value I need is not available)

```
        if (count($entities)>0)
        {
            foreach ($entities as $entity)
            {
                if (!term_exists($entity, 'entity'))
                {
                    wp_insert_term($entity, 'entity');
                }
            }
            wp_set_object_terms($post_id, array_map('sanitize_title', $entities), 'entity', false);
        }
```

The weirdest thing is that `wp_set_object_terms` returns array of term_taxonomy_ids of terms, meaning it inserted them successfully (according to Codex) but they're actually not there. Any ideas what I might be missing here?